# Upgrading opam on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ocaml, opam

I'm trying to upgrade my opam to the latest version of Ubuntu 14.04

```
chris@chris-870Z5E-880Z5E-680Z5E:~$ sudo opam update
default    Downloading https://opam.ocaml.org/1.1/urls.txt
Updating ~/.opam/repo/compiler-index ...
Updating ~/.opam/compilers/ ...
Updating ~/.opam/repo/package-index ...
Updating ~/.opam/packages/ ...
The following package has been DELETED:
 - camlp4.4.02.0+2
[WARNING] install and dev-repo are unknown fields in /home/chris/.opam/repo/default/packages/liquidsoap/liquidsoap.1.1.1/opam: is your OPAM up-to-date ?
[WARNING] install is an unknown field in /home/chris/.opam/repo/default/packages/ocurl/ocurl.0.7.2/opam: is your OPAM up-to-date ?
Updating the cache of metadata (~/.opam/state.cache) ...
23 to install | 17 to reinstall | 16 to upgrade | 1 to downgrade | 0 to remove
You can now run 'opam upgrade' to upgrade your system.
chris@chris-870Z5E-880Z5E-680Z5E:~$ sudo opam upgrade
[WARNING] External solver failed with inconsistent return value. Request saved to "/home/chris/.opam/log/solver-error-6572-1.cudf"
Falling back to the internal heuristic.

The dependency ocamlbuild of package variantslib.109.15.03 is not available for your compiler or your OS.
'opam upgrade' failed.
```

As the error message says, it appears that `variantslib.109.15.03` is not available on my OS/compiler version. Is there any way I can get around this? Here is my compiler version:

```
chris@chris-870Z5E-880Z5E-680Z5E:~$ ocaml -version
The OCaml toplevel, version 4.02.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, don't use `sudo` as `opam` is installed in your user folder, so you may actually break it by locking it from yourself. (I think you already did it). In general, don't use `sudo` if you're not absolutely sure what you're doing.

The solver is unable to find a package variantslib that will fit into constraints of your system. If you're installing or using some package, that you believe should work for the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, then I would suggest you just to start from a clean state and install it, instead of performing the update. Since you already messed with sudo, I would actually suggest you to remove the `~/.opam` folder, and start with

```
opam init
```

And install whatever you need from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well, I had some issues with opam 1.1 in the past... And the [opam FAQ](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/FAQ.html) states that you should move to opam 1.2 (because of : [ubuntu bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/opam/+bug/1401346)).... I personally use opam 1.2.2 (on ubuntu 16.04 & 12.04...)